# GCM no message received in chrome for mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on a chrome app which receives notification using GCM from a publisher. It is working just fine on linux. However when testing the app on a Mac OSX I never receive any messages even though the registration happen successfully. Nothing appears in the dev console, no exception.

```js
function messageReceived(message) {
  console.log("Message received: " + messageString);
}

chrome.gcm.onMessage.addListener(messageReceived);
console.log('App loaded')
```

Is there anyone experiencing the same problem?

Comment: If the push notification works on the `linux`, it should be work on mac. It not about the OS, please check your `chrome version` on mac. It seems that you didnt get the message because nothing shows on your `console`. Please check the doc here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client#write_chrome_app_or_extension

Comment: My chrome version on the mac is 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit) which seems to be up to date. The app is working fine on the platform Windows, Linux. But not working on Mac.